# How to test Concourse pipelines

Tags: concourse

My team has multiple Concourse pipelines and as we refactor tasks, we've realized the need to test our actual pipelines.

We already test our tasks by using environment variables enabling task scripts to be run locally, but the pipeline yaml is another matter.

What is the best way to accomplish testing of the pipeline itself?

Comment: What kinds of tests do you want to run specifically?

Comment: I'm wondering how I can find out before my entire pipeline goes red that someone has done something like misconfigure the resource pool lock or the git release resource for instance.  In production code, our tests would tell us these things, so that's why I say I'm looking for how to test the pipeline itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Concourse Pipeline Resource](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-pipeline-resource) to monitor the git repository where you keep your pipeline config. Whenever the pipeline resource detects a change, it will automatically run a `fly set-pipeline` to update the config in your running Concourse installation. From there, it's easy to script tests against the updated pipeline that is now running in your Concourse installation.

Answer (score 0):

`fly validate-pipeline` is pretty useful, running that against pipelines before merging has caught a few bugs in "obviously correct" changes for me.

If you want to test the whole pipeline before merging you need to make sure that the data it's using is static and working (no sense in failing the pipeline if it's the repo that's broken), and that there are no side effects (like notifications) shared between the 'real pipeline' and the 'test pipeline'. I suspect that as long as you're careful with the restrictions, you could make it work, but it would have to be designed in the context of your existing pipelines and infrastructure.